# Re-export local Variables in Typescript properly with the Name unchanged

Tags: typescript, export

In order to find a not so ugly solution for my [clientside module bundle problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891901/how-to-bundle-a-clientside-typescript-project) I found out that I can tell Typescript to export variables from the local scope as part of the module. But something is weird and I'd like to show you in the following mini-example.

Say I have the following three files in the same directory.

#### Red.ts

```
class Red {}
```

#### Blue.ts

```
class Blue {}
```

#### colors.ts

```
/// <reference path="Blue"/>
/// <reference path="Red"/>

export var Red = Red;
export var Blue = Blue;
```

As I'm building a clientside module, I'm using AMD as module format, getting the following Javascript output from Typescript.

#### Output

```
var Blue = (function () {
    function Blue() {
    }
    return Blue;
}());
var Red = (function () {
    function Red() {
    }
    return Red;
}());
define("colors", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    exports.Red = exports.Red; // this just assigns undefined
    exports.Blue = exports.Blue; // his just assigns undefined
});
```

I tried using:

```
export var Red;
export var Blue;
```

But in that case Typescript doesn't generate any code for these statements at all.

I'd actually like it to produce the following export statements:

```
exports.Red = Red;
exports.Blue = Blue;
```

I know I could just temporarily rename the variables like:

```
var Red_ = Red;
var Blue_ = Blue;
export Red = Red_;
export Blue = Blue_;
```

Or also do it in a loop with a map and stuff, but what would be the proper way of doing this?

#### Questions

So, to make it easier, choose one or more questions from the following:

1. Is there a nice way to tell Typescript to properly re-export these variables without a name change?
2. Is there a better practice to achieve what I want so that my problem just disappears?
3. Is this a Typescript bug? (In that case I'd submit a bug report.)

#### Further important Constraints

It is not an option for me to export the classes on their own (`export class Red ...` in *Red.ts* and for *Blue.ts* respectively), then re-export them in *colors.ts* like Aluan Haddad described [in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909518/2477364), because I do not want any class to get a define-statement in order to keep a clean global environment.

The aim is to be able to require the result (`colors.js`) and have one object granting access to some parts of the whole. **As a second step after compiling the Typescript I'd enclose the whole script in a function so that all global variables become local and only the define statement will define an interface to the whole script functionality.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing global code and module code.
The "reference path" construct is for using globals declared in other files. 
While this appears to have been an accident in your case, in general try to avoid mixing global code and module code wherever possible.

Try the following instead

**red.ts**

```
export class Red {}
```

**blue.ts**

```
export class Blue {}
```

**colors.ts**

```
export {Red} from './red';
export {Blue} from './blue';
```

To elaborate, files are not modules unless they contain a top-level `import` or `export` statement. Since your **red** and **blue** files did not import or export anything they were simply defining global variables.

Comment: Of course this is a valid answer to my question. Unfortunately I just forgot to mention why this is not an option for me. I've updated the question. Thank you for your answer, though.

Comment: I'm not sure why allowing someone to import red or blue directly is a problem. If it is you need to place them in the same module file. The role of modules is code organization and code isolation (within a single module), not encapsulation. Thinking about modules in terms of how your bundle ultimately looks may not be the right approach as it is a distribution level concern only. The shape of your API should not change because of how you decide to package it to meet the ever changing ways in which it is necessary to improve performance.

Comment: The reason is to avoid naming conflicts. What if I have another module that adds classes with these names. I'm aiming at a quality that lets me release it as a library and such a script should never pollute the global namespace with internal classes that have generic names.

Comment: It won't put the global namespace at all that's the whole point. Just don't use globals and everything is fine. Any other library exporting values with these names will NOT conflict because they will be identified by their respective import specifiers which will definitely be different because they're coming from different libraries that are installed in different locations.

Comment: I think I found out where I was misunderstanding things. I thought of `define('foo', ...)` as polluting the global name `foo`, but, actually, it will automatically be relative to the script's directory path, thus it won't occupy a global name (unless I put it into the main script directory). I had the *jQuery* library in mind the whole time, which only provides one variable as interface to the whole library. That's a special case then, though, because *jQuery* was made to work without the require semantics and was only made compatible with it afterwards. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's mostly correct, but don't use a named `define`, `define('foo', ...)` because that will cause a clash if multiple modules declare it or if multiple versions of the same library are used. Use an anonymous `define`, `define(...)`, in a file named foo instead. Tools like require RequireJS, SystemJS, and TypeScript will automatically create a named define when building a bundle but this will be done in such a way as to not cause conflicts. JQuery is, as a colleague of mine would say, a special snowflake and rightly gets to do things that others should not. Don't manually use name to defines.